# Jquery change event on miltiline text field (plain text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiline-text-field

I have tried to set up an onchange event to be triggered on a Multiline (Plain) Text field. I have tried all the following without luck.

```
$("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").change(function(){
alert('Action 1');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).bind('input', function() {
alert('Action 2');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).on('input', function() {
alert('Action 3');});

$("input[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']").change(function(){
alert('Action 3');});

$($("input[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).change(function(){
alert('Action 4');});

$("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().change(function(){
alert('Action 5');});

$("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").change(function(){
alert('Action 6');});

$("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").change(function(){
alert('Action 7');});

$("textarea[title='Identified Tasks']").change(function(){
alert('Action 8');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).change(function(){
alert('Action 9');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).closest("span").change(function(){
alert('Action 10');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).children().change(function(){
alert('Action 11');});

$($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks]")[0]).change(function(){
alert('Action 12');});

var systemDescriptionRTE = $("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().find("body"); 

ar systemDescriptionRTE = $("textarea[Title='Identified Tasks']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().find("body").find("span");
    $(systemDescriptionRTE).change(function(){
alert('Action 13');});

$("textarea[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']").change(function(){
alert('Action 14');});

$("textarea[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte'][0]").change(function(){
alert('Action 15');});

$("textarea[title='Identified Tasks']").change(function(){
alert('Action 16');});

$slogDiv.on('change', function(e){
alert('Action 18');});

var $slogDiv = $("[id^='Identified_x0020_Tasks'][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']");

  $slogDiv.on('change', function(e){
alert('Action 20');});
```

The following code does work

```
var $slogDiv = $("[id^='Identified_x0020_Tasks'][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']");

 $slogDiv.on('click keyup', function(e){
alert('Action 19');});

alert($($("[id^=Identified_x0020_Tasks][id$='$TextField_inplacerte']")[0]).text())
```

So I seem to have the selector correct. Any ideas on how to attach a change event on it?

The clickup event does work, but multiple times, not just once as expected from a change event.

Any suggestions on what coding I need?

Comment: Are you working on Modern Page or Classic Page?

Comment: Standard on-premise Sp2013 newform and editform...

Comment: I tried with $slogDiv.on('change', function(e){alert('Action 20');}); and it is working fine.

Comment: Arrggghh.. no this won't fire on my page!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this to work. Ended up modifying the presaveaction section and in this section did a before / after comparison of the field and did a jQuery update on that field if a change had been detected.